# How to solve Bazel with Gazelle grep error

Tags: go, bazel

I'm using the Bazel with Gazelle in my golang project.(Windows environment)
I think everything is installed and set properly.
But I enter the "bazel run -s //:gazelle" in CMD
Can anyone help?Thank you!
[image]

Comment: Make sure you delete this .idea/BUILD.bazel file from your repo. [Reference](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-gazelle/issues/894#issuecomment-688922179_

Comment: Hi, I don't find any idea/BUILD.bazel file in my directory. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue of how the Gazelle launch script finds the manifest file. If you open "execroot\code\bazel-out\x64_windows-fastbuild\bin\gazelle", you will find the bash script that is invoked when running gazelle.

Remove write protection, and go to line 39:

```
  if grep -q "^$runfile" "$0.runfiles_manifest"; then
    grep "^$runfile" "$0.runfiles_manifest" | head -n 1 | cut -d' ' -f2
    return
```

Note that this part of the script searches for `$0.runfiles_manifest`. `$0` is the script being run, so `gazelle` On my system, the file `gazelle.runfiles_manifest` does not exist, but `gazelle.exe.runfiles_manifest` does. I therefore added the `.exe` extension here, and at least that part of the script completed.

However, it didn't help me much - even if the `grep` command succeeds, some subsequent error happens.

```
INFO: Analyzed target //:gazelle (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //:gazelle up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/gazelle-runner.bash
  bazel-bin/gazelle
  bazel-bin/gazelle.exe
INFO: Elapsed time: 3.659s, Critical Path: 0.02s
INFO: 1 process: 1 internal.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
INFO: Running command line: bazel-bin/gazelle.exe
2023/05/15 17:22:57 failed to initialize parser: Runfile python/parse: could not locate file
```

I am using bazel version 6.1.2. In any case, it is probably better to open an issue on GitHub to get better support.